# ffmpeg rtsp error: Nonmatching transport in server reply

Tags: ffmpeg, c++, rtsp

I'm using `ffmpeg` to read an rtsp camera. I'm getting these errors:
`Nonmatching transport in server reply` in c++ and `Invalid data found when processing input`.
I can play this in VLC in Windows. I'm using Red Hat 6.9.
The camera has the setting "RTP ES".

The code:

```
source_name = "rtsp://192.168.1.108/WESCAM";

// Open the initial context variables that are needed
format_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();    
codec_ctx = NULL;

// Register everything
av_register_all();
avformat_network_init();

//open RTSP camera or h264 file
if (avformat_open_input(&format_ctx, source_name, NULL, NULL) != 0) 
{
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
source_name = "rtsp://192.168.1.108/WESCAM";
```

Some formatting issues with my post here's the code

```
// Open the initial context variables that are needed

format_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();    
codec_ctx = NULL;

// Register everything

av_register_all();

avformat_network_init();


//open RTSP camera or h264 file

if (avformat_open_input(&format_ctx, source_name, NULL, NULL) != 0) 
{
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```